# Escp command to print table border

Tags: printing

I am working on Epson dot matrix printer and printing using Esc/p command. But I have problem when i want to print a border of table. The table border will use the extended ASCII :
[image]

So I want to use character : 179, 180, 185, 186, etc.... But when I send it to printer, it print strange character. So how to make it work?

I am trying to select character set but it seems still not work. If anyone know about, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

There are several sets of ASCII tables in the printer.
The printer documentation shows which table is default.

To send extended character to printer, it must be written as hex byte:

```
data="\xC9" # example extended byte
```

If you need more precise answer, please let us know which printer you are using, show example of your code.

Comment: Yes, i have sent it as hex. But it does not work. I am using c++ and Qt as the programming language. I build the command using QByteArray, nothing special for the command just init command and the text. And send the byte to printer.

Comment: Just an idea: to verify the printer has the same extended ASCII table as you think it has, print all the table bytes (or at least several around the code of your interest).

Comment: But is it possible to change the table?

Comment: In my printer yes, by issuing "\x1BR\xNN", where NN is a hexadecimal byte specifying which table, and there are very many of them.

Please download YOUR printer ESC/P reference, and read it.